# My German Schengen Visa allows me to enter the country on Dec 12. Can I book my departure flight on late evening of Dec 11th?

Tags: schengen, germany, schengen-visas

So I applied for the German Schengen visa recently and got approved. the thing is, in my document I asked for a period of about 20 days from December 11th 2021 to Jan 2022. But the visa came back with "FROM: 12-12-2021". Can I still keep my original itinerary, which has the departure flight on evening Dec 11 (**departs at 20:00 from Toronto - it will takes 7-8hrs to land in Frankfurt**) and land on the early morning of Dec 12? Would the border police nitpick that part and not allow me to enter my plane?

Comment: For completeness, what time in the early morning would you expect to arrive? And where are you travelling from? If the scheduled arrival time is very soon after midnight, your biggest problem might be the airline allowing you to board, especially if there’s a chance the flight might arrive esrly.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have edited my post. I'm flying from Toronto and it will take approximately 8hrs to land at Frankfurt's airport. My flight departs at 20:00 on Dec 11 so I will land on Germany's soil on Dec 12 early morning-ish.

Comment: So you actually depart Dec 12 02:00 CET (German time)

Comment: If it was not that you are already landing on the 12.12.2021, you could always have a nap of some hours in the toilets on your way from the plane to the security check.

Answer (score 2):

Your departure date (2021-12-11 20:00 EST) is 2021-12-12 02:00 CET.

The date of arrival (and departure) on the corresponding passport stamp is what counts.

I don't recall any regulation that deals with any timezone difference between WET (Portugal), CET and EET (Finland/Greece), so assume that the local timezone of the country that issues the passport stamp is what counts.